# Cant get my divs positioned correctly

Tags: css, html

Honestly - CSS and Divs aint the thing i'm most familiar with. However, I thought that I had managed to make the template for my later design, but it turns out that everything tends to move a bit around for me..

In Chrome, things seems to work at first, but after refreshing a few times, the text "your position on page" jumps down to the next line. In firefox, things are just at the wrong places to begin with.

If possibly, I would also like a nod on, how to get a padding/margin between the position text and again between each line. When adding it now, it just moves everything to completely wrong places.

Demo: http://cityroast.dk

**CSS:**

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #e8ebef;
    padding: 5px;
}
div#catcontainer {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
div#categories {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
div#ads {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    float: left;
    display: box;
}
div#ads span {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12;
    text-align: left;
}
div#one {
    width: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
div#two {
    width: 70%;
    height: 80px;
    background: aqua;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
div#three {
    width: 10%;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 80px;
}
div a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <div id="catcontainer">
        <div id="categories">
            <ul>
                <b>A menu</b>
                <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Something2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Something3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ads">
        <span>Your position on page</span>
        <div id="one">A picture</div>
        <div id="two"><b>Title</b></div>
        <div id="three"><b>Details</b></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Obviously, the latter part of the code is echoed 5 times at the moment, to get the 5 lines.

Thanks already!

Comment: I edited your post and improved formatting. First of all: You have a non-list element inside your `<ul>`. Put `<b>A menu</b>` outside of the list (right before the `<ul>` tag). Also don't use your live page as a demo. Use jsfiddle.net instead, please. This way future visitors will be able to see your problem.

Comment: I've copied your code into a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yochannah/Dgbf6/ and a slightly updated one to address kleinfreund's point here: http://jsfiddle.net/yochannah/Dgbf6/2/. My question is, though, it's not entirely clear to me what you're *wanting* this to look like. Do you have a sketch or mockup that conveys what you are looking for?

Comment: Ty!! Any ideas about how I get everything positioned correctly?

The goal im looking for at the moment is something like this:
http://tinypic.com/r/2mpk6qx/5

Obviously, it's not the final design, but its what I want it to look like at this stage. Chrome actually manages to show it like this - some of the times..

Comment: at first please put this in ur CSS code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Exr5w/

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML That might be a bit confusing for him. Setting `body { margin: 0; }` is totally enough.

Comment: Correct your errors first. 1) Don't use Quirks mode; it's horrible. Especially when you're targeting HTML5. 2) While the start and end tags on `html`, `head` and `body` are indeed all optional, it is good practice to include them anyway. 3) Use a `<title>`. 4) ids should be unique. 5) The layout of the source is really dreadful. Normally I wouldn't mind, but since you're asking for help with it, it should be properly formatted and indented. Then we'll talk.

Comment: Hey everybody. Thanks for your inputs!! I will indeed follow used conventions in the final design, but at the moment it is totally a draft, so i dont mind head, body, title and stuff.. The design is a draft also, that Im going to work more on at a later stage..

I have added the mentioned http://fiddle.jshell.net/Exr5w/

Now it works in chrome, but firefox still moves the "position" text towards the center, and the picture up. Have a look at this screenshot:
http://cityroast.dk/divnow.jpg